# Error occur: crypto_aead_chacha20poly1305_keybytes long when saving password in some payment module

Tags: magento2, payment-methods

Do anyone know what is the problem?

[image]

[image]

is this a php versio problem? i'm using webtatic 7.1.22 version

update: also installed sodium still not work
[image]

Comment: mention your magento version

Comment: @MohitRane magento 2.3 ce

Answer (score 0):

The key you are trying to save should be 32 bytes, its checked in vendor/paragonie/sodium_compat/src/Compat.php:

```
vendor/paragonie/sodium_compat/src/Compat.php:56:    
const CRYPTO_AEAD_CHACHA20POLY1305_KEYBYTES = 32;

vendor/paragonie/sodium_compat/src/Compat.php:366:        
if (ParagonIE_Sodium_Core_Util::strlen($key) !== self::CRYPTO_AEAD_CHACHA20POLY1305_KEYBYTES) {

vendor/paragonie/sodium_compat/src/Compat.php:367:            
throw new SodiumException('Key must be CRYPTO_AEAD_CHACHA20POLY1305_KEYBYTES long');

vendor/paragonie/sodium_compat/src/Compat.php:446:        
if (ParagonIE_Sodium_Core_Util::strlen($key) !== self::CRYPTO_AEAD_CHACHA20POLY1305_KEYBYTES) {

vendor/paragonie/sodium_compat/src/Compat.php:447:            
throw new SodiumException('Key must be CRYPTO_AEAD_CHACHA20POLY1305_KEYBYTES long');

vendor/paragonie/sodium_compat/src/Compat.php:520:        
if (ParagonIE_Sodium_Core_Util::strlen($key) !== self::CRYPTO_AEAD_CHACHA20POLY1305_KEYBYTES) {

vendor/paragonie/sodium_compat/src/Compat.php:521:            
throw new SodiumException('Key must be CRYPTO_AEAD_CHACHA20POLY1305_KEYBYTES long');

vendor/paragonie/sodium_compat/src/Compat.php:574:        
return random_bytes(self::CRYPTO_AEAD_CHACHA20POLY1305_KEYBYTES);

vendor/paragonie/sodium_compat/src/Compat.php:613:        
if (ParagonIE_Sodium_Core_Util::strlen($key) !== self::CRYPTO_AEAD_CHACHA20POLY1305_KEYBYTES) {

vendor/paragonie/sodium_compat/src/Compat.php:614:            
throw new SodiumException('Key must be CRYPTO_AEAD_CHACHA20POLY1305_KEYBYTES long');
```

The value of $key is set in env.php, make sure the value is still 32 bytes:

```
return [
    'backend' => [
        'frontName' => 'admin'
    ],
    'crypt' => [
        'key' => '95495a570338c9af98e3172dbd219857'
    ],
```

Comment: so what is the possible solution?

Comment: are you using a key provided by stripe? if so, maybe you should get in touch with their support

Comment: there is a same issue about the amazon_core amazon_login amazon_XXXX, i need to disable 3 amazon modules able to access the payment method store configuration, so i think it should be php/mysql settings problem?

Comment: seems every config use <backend_model>Magento\Config\Model\Config\Backend\Encrypted</backend_model> will have this problem

Comment: I log the file in your answer ParagonIE_Sodium_Core_Util::strlen($key), there is only 8 str len

Comment: maybe you can try to use php 7.2 and check if that changes anything?

Comment: i have two testing websites in centos 6 running php7 have this problem, but one testing website in centos 7 don't not have this problem

Comment: i just found vendor\magento\module-config\Model\Config\Backend\Encrypted.php do not encrypt the value in those website in centos 6

Comment: i finally know the problems because i changed the crypt_key in env.php ti Abcd123 should it doesn't work :(

Comment: great!! just updated the answer so it holds the solution and is useful for any one facing this issue!